# NestJS TypeORM How to correctly type the OR conditional in a query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I currently have this code to get my results

```
rolesCanAssign = await this.rolesRepository.find({
            

where: {
    VALCompany: user.VALCompany,
},
```

But I need to add an OR operator to this WHERE and I wanted to do it like this

```
where: [{VALCompany:user.VALCompany},{isNull(VALCompany)}]
```

I get an error saying I was expecting a '{'.
So for the moment use the following but I would like to type it like the previous example

code that currently works for me:

```
where: 'VALCompany IS NULL or VALCompany IN (' + user.VALCompany + ')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the second part, you should do:

```
where: [{VALCompany:user.VALCompany},{VALCompany:isNull()}]
```